# Copying files on mounted drive

Tags: php, linux, windows, shell

So I had to write a script that will separate certain images on a network file server and back them up preserving the file structure. To do this, I am mounting the file server as a folder on my linux box where the script will be running. The file server is a windows box.

The file server was mounted like this:

```
mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/pictures$ -o username=imageuser,password=pa$$word images
```

If I run a copy command like this:

```
cp images/somefolder/subfolder/someimage.jpg images/differentfolder/subfolder/someimage.jpg
```

My question is this:

**Will "someimage.jpg" be simply be copied from one location to the other on the windows machine, or will the image be downloaded to the linux box over the network and then uploaded to the new location on the windows machine?**

Edit: If the file will be round-tripped - I would like to know how to do it without that or at least to be pointed in the right direction where I can read up on a way to do it.

Comment: The file will be round-tripped through your client. The cp command isn't smart enough to realize that the source and destination of the file are on the same remote machine. Nor should it really care - its job is to copy, not figure out where a file is and if any optimizations could be applied.

Comment: Is there any way to do that from my linux box?

Comment: Use a remote ssh command, e.g. `ssh imageuser@x.x.x.x 'cp source target'`, which would be purely a server-side operation, and keep the file's data within the server itself, never roundtripping it to the client.

Comment: @hek2mgl: yeah, rewrote the comment to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `cp` nor the `smb` protocol are smart enough to realize that the source + destination of the file are on the same remote server. cp will simply do its usual thing and slurp all the data from the source file (copying it to the client machine), then spit it back out in the target file on the server. So yes, it'll be a round-trip through the client.

A better solution for this sort of thing is using an SSH remote command, turning it into a purely server-side operation:

```
ssh imageuser@x.x.x.x 'cp sourcefile targetfile'
```

You can still keep the fileserver mounted on your local machine to actually see what files you're dealing with, but do all the file copy/move operations via the ssh commands for efficiency. Since the server is a Windows machine, you'll probably have to install cygwin and get an ssh server running.

Comment: Thanks for the help - after talking to the server admin, he doesn't want to do this. I am just going to use my script to generate a .bat script for him to run on the server. I am going to mark your answer as correct though because it would clearly work much better!

Comment: if it was windows->windows, you could use psexec or other "remote exec" tools to do a `copy` on the windows box directly. not sure if anything's available for linux-side that could tie into the same systems that psexec uses.